# Tensorflow: What is the equivalent of dense layer from Tensorflow in Caffe?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, caffe, layer

In tensorflow in order to add a dense layer I have:

model.add(Dense(1024, activation='selu'))

How can I pass this Dense Layer in Keras To Caffe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dense layer is called InnerProduct in caffe Look at [this](https://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers/innerproduct.html) for a sample code
Also check this [link](https://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers) to help you with other types of layers

Comment: Thanks again! Dou you know what happen in this case: model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))